# En Python Pandas ¿Cómo rellenar una columna de un DataFrame dividiendo dos columnas?

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un DataFrame en el cual hay 5 columnas (A, B, C, D y E), deseo generar una columa F la cual se calcule dependiedo del valor de A por ejemplo:

> Si 'A' = 1, entonces 'F' = 'B'/'C' ,
>   Si 'A' = 2, entonces 'F' =  'B'/'D' 
>   o  Si 'A' = 3, entonces 'F' = 'B'/'E'

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,3,2,1], 'B':[0,1,1,0,2,1], \
 'C':[0,1.0,1,0,2,0], 'D':[1,0,1,0,1,0], 'F':[0,0,0,1,1,1]})
```

Al utilizar:

```
df.loc[(df["A"]==1), "E"]=(df["B"]/df["C"])
df.loc[(df["A"]==2), "E"]=(df["B"]/df["D"])
df.loc[(df["A"]==3), "E"]=(df["B"]/df["F"])
```

en la columna F aparece inf o en el DataFrame Real se general el error

```
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

¿De que forma se pueden hacer estos cálculos de tal manera que cuando se encuentre en el denominador un valor CERO, en el registro se ponga un valor de CERO y no inf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mi lo que me ha servido es usar la paquetería `numpy`, en específico la función `where`. Yo lo haría algo así (aunque parezca bastante largo, creo que es más claro):

```
import numpy as np
df["F"] = np.where(df["A"] == 1, df["B"] / df["C"], 0)
df["F"] = np.where(df["A"] == 2, df["B"] / df["D"], df["F"])
df["F"] = np.where(df["A"] == 3, df["B"] / df["E"], df["F"])
```

Comment: Hola @Gaspar Gracias por la respuesta, pero el problema no está en la elección de la división, mas bien está en que en cualquiera de los casos se encuentra una división por cero y marca un error o llena el registro con inf. lo que necesito es que al hacer el cálculo cuando se encuentre un cero en el denominador, en lugar de hacer la operación, llene el registro con un CERO.

Comment: En todo caso aplica la misma función, pero ahora revisa que el denominador sea distinto de cero.

Comment: Una disculpa por no comentar antes, seguí tus instrucciones y obtuve el resultado deseado. muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

En versiones recientes de Pandas (no así si usas NumPy) al dividir dos series entre si, ante un denominador que sea 0  obtendrás `inf` (infinito) sin el numerador no es 0 o `NaN` si el numerador es también 0, no es algo que puedas redefinir. Simplemente substituye los valores `inf`/`-inf` de la columna por 0 una vez rellenada usando [`pandas.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,3,2,1],
                   'B': [0,1,1,0,2,1],
                   'C': [0,1,1,0,2,0],
                   'D': [1,0,1,0,1,0],
                   'F': [0,0,0,1,1,1]
                   }) 


df.loc[df["A"] == 1, "E"] = df["B"] / df["C"]
df.loc[df["A"] == 2, "E"] = df["B"] / df["D"]
df.loc[df["A"] == 3, "E"] = df["B"] / df["F"]
df["E"].replace((np.inf, -np.inf), 0, inplace=True)
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>    A  B  C  D  F    E
> 0  1  0  0  1  0  NaN
> 1  2  1  1  0  0  0.0
> 2  3  1  1  1  0  0.0
> 3  3  0  0  0  1  0.0
> 4  2  2  2  1  1  2.0
> 5  1  1  0  0  1  0.0
> ```

Si quieres incluir el caso de `NaN` (0 / 0) entonces puedes hacer:

```
df["E"].replace((np.inf, -np.inf, np.nan), 0, inplace=True)
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>    A  B  C  D  F    E
> 0  1  0  0  1  0  0.0
> 1  2  1  1  0  0  0.0
> 2  3  1  1  1  0  0.0
> 3  3  0  0  0  1  0.0
> 4  2  2  2  1  1  2.0
> 5  1  1  0  0  1  0.0
> ```

Otra opción es asignar 0 como valor por defecto a la columna de salida (`E`) y luego dividir solo las filas en las que el denominador no es 0 mediante una máscara boleana:

```
df["E"] = 0
df.loc[(df["A"] == 1) & df["C"], "E"] = df["B"] / df["C"]
df.loc[(df["A"] == 2) & df["D"], "E"] = df["B"] / df["D"]
df.loc[(df["A"] == 3) & df["F"], "E"] = df["B"] / df["F"]
```